# Modify string if original does not match particular string

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a file with millions of rows and want to modify values in column A only if the string is '.'. The modification would be to add `"chr:"$2":"$3` to the start of the string. All other rows would be printed as the original version.

**Example Input:**

```
A B C D E F G H
rs125 2 5433 T TACA A 3 2
chr2:4543 2 4543 I R 8 2
rs123 3 4332 A C 9 3
. 3 7654 I R 8
```

Above, the 4th row begins with '.' and needs to be changed to 'chr3:7654'. All other rows need to remain unchanged.

**Desired Output:**

```
A B C D E F G H
rs125 2 5433 T TACA A 3 2
chr2:4543 2 4543 I R 8 2
rs123 3 4332 A C 9 3
chr3:7654 3 7654 I R 8 2
```

My code so far works but changes ALL names to begin 'chr...' even when 'rs...' should remain unchanged:

```
awk '($1 ~ /^./) {$1 = "chr:"$2":"$3}1' filename > newfilename
```

It is probably a very simple solution but it is causing very big problems.
Thanks!

Comment: The period (`.`) is a metacharacter in regex (which I'm assuming awk is using here). Try escaping it (`\.`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is the regex. `/^./` will match any valid character at start of line. You must escape `.` to match it literally:

```
awk '$1 ~ /^\./ {$1 = "chr:"$2":"$3};1' filename > newfilename
```

But it's better to just check for string equal instead of doing regex checking:

```
awk '$1 == "." {$1 = "chr:"$2":"$3};1' filename > newfilename
```

Comment: I used the second option of string equal and seems to work perfectly. Thanks @cuonglm